# How to show the default constructor in Doxygen generated documentation?

Tags: c++, c++11, doxygen

Having a class A:

```
class A {
public:
    /// @brief constructor taking no param
    A() {}
    /// @brief constructor taking 1 param
    /// @param[in] x x
    A(int x) {}
    /// @brief constructor taking 2 params
    /// @param[in] x x
    /// @param[in] y y
    A(int x, int y) {}
};
```

After generating documentation using Doxygen the "Constructor & Destructor Documentation" section will contain the documentation for constructors `A(int x)` and `A(int x, int y)`. However not for `A()`.

Is there any flag I can set to force Doxygen to include the constructor for `A()` in the relevant section of the class documentation?

**Edit:** I had to edit my original code as it seems to depend on having a `@param` whether the code is documented in the "Constructor & Destructor Documentation" section by default.

The output by Doxygen version 1.8.16:
[image]

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Why would it skip that? Can you show a screenshot? Are you sure you've rebuilt your documentation since adding the constructor?

Comment: Also relevant information is: which doxygen version are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I posted a screen and made a small edit. Bit closer to the reason as it seems I must add at least one \@param for a constructor to show up at all.

Comment: @albert I added the version to the post right before the image. It's version 1.8.16.

Comment: What about up top? Maybe that section you're looking at only lists things with parameters.

Comment: Note that, due to copy / paste, you documented `x` twice` and didn't comment `y`

Comment: @albert thanks for noticing. Cleaned up that typo for anyone coming here in the future. I think the answer has been posted. Need to go and try the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method etc. is not shown by default in the detailed section like 'Constructor & Destructor Documentation' when there is no detailed documentation (or parameter documentation etc.). By setting:
`ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC=YES`
you will get also the "missing" constructor.

Note have also a look at e.g. `REPEAT_BRIEF`.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_project):

> **`ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC`**
>
> If the `ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC` and `REPEAT_BRIEF` tags are both set to `YES` then doxygen will generate a detailed section even if there is only a brief description.
>
> The default value is: `NO`.

As such, you *should* find the ctor listed up top; it just doesn't get its own "detailed" description by default, because there are no details to give.

Answer (score 1):

The documented constructor has non non-brief documentation content. As such, that constructor doesn't get its own block of documentation. It will appear in the brief listing, but not in the full listing.

So you should give the constructor some non-brief content.

Comment: Might be better to configure the tool rather than hack in documentation that isn't warranted in order to work around the bad configuration

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I agree on that. Adding for example an @ param to it to force it to be listed feels wrong. This does work as it seems but is not the preferred solution (at least not mine).

Comment: @LightnessRaces: That all depends on whether you see it as a "bad configuration" or not. A documented entity without non-brief content doesn't need a detailed entry because... it's not complicated enough to need one. If a one liner sufficies to explain the function, why does it need a giant block of text, when the one-liner is present in the brief documentation?

Comment: @NicolBolas Granted - substitute "bad configuration" for "configuration undesired by this particular OP" :)